# Sas input informat (invalid argument)

Tags: sas, format

How do I format this date from character to numeric? Is it only possible in the first input statement? This is the data step and the error

```
data new;
input a $;
cards;
01JAN1999
;
run;

data test;
set new;
a_format = input (a, date9.);
run;

NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT at line 82 column 12.
 a=01JAN199 a_format=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
 NOTE: Mathematical operations could not be performed at the following places. The results of the operations have been set to 
       missing values.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the date value directly in the first step.  Be sure to format the variable so that the value is human readable when a procedure such as `Proc PRINT` outputs the value.

*(Note: INFORMAT defines how a sequence of characters is to be parsed into an underlying value and FORMAT defines how an underlying value is rendered as a series of characters)*

```
data want;
  input mydatevar date9.;
  format mydatevar date9.;
datalines;
01JAN1999
;
```

The default length for character variables named in an `INPUT` statement is `$8.`
Your biggest clue is the log itself showing you **`a=01JAN199`**.

Specify the variable length with any of these in `DATA new` and the `INPUT()` function in `DATA test` will work:

`LENGTH` statement before the `INPUT`:

- `LENGTH A $9;`
  `INPUT a;`

`ATTRIB` statement before the `INPUT`:

- `ATTRIB A length=$9;`
  `INPUT a;`

Inferred from informat specified as part of the `INPUT` statement:

- `INPUT a $9.;`